# Add elements to an array from specified position in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am adding elements to array `arr1` using map function. Is there any way to specify the index of starting position in `typescript`

**e.g** If I want to add elements from 3rd index position of the array. first two index should hold 0. how can I do that?

```js
let years = [0,1,2,3,4];

data = {
      var1: 100000,
      arr2: years.map(_ => 1000)
    };
    
console.log(data.arr2);
```

I want to add 0 from starting of the array. If I specify position as 3 then first 2 element should be zero

Comment: Are you aware your code snippet doesn't work ? I don' understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Florian Sorry. Updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` and for all index value lower than your desired index place 0 other get the value from your array.

```js
let years = [0,1,2,3,4],
    index = 2,
    result = years.map((v,i) => i < index ? 0 : v);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood what you want :

```js
let years = [0,1,2,3,4];

data = {
      var1: 100000,
      arr2: modifyArray(3, 100000)
    };

console.log(data.arr2);

function modifyArray(position = 0, value) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < position - 1; i++) {
    newArray.push(0);
  }
  return [...newArray, ...years.slice(0, position ), value, ...years.slice(position)];
}
```